# Pebble.js ajax request with post data. No data in request

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, pebble-js

I just started fiddeling with pebble.js for a prototype. I have to make a connection to a server and send user data from the pebble (login information) to the server for a handshake and send back data from the server to the pebble. I am using pebble.js because its easy for prototyping.

Now I am using the ajax library (http://developer.getpebble.com/docs/pebblejs/#ajax) to setup the connection. I have the following code:

```
ajax(
{
  url: URL,
  method: 'post',
  type: 'json',
  data: {
    auth : 'test'
  }
},
function(data) {
  // Success!
  console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
},
function(error) {
  // Failure!
  console.log('no response');
}
);
```

In PHP on the server I get the complete header information by apache_request_headers(); and send it to the pebble with echo json_encode(apache_request_headers());

This results in an output of console.log(JSON.stringify(data))

```
{"Host":"192.168.0.113","Content-Type":"application/json","Accept":"*/*","Connection":"keep-alive","Cookie":"v2ci_session=55MmpPmzb2cvBWiq3VNgneHexYzBtIFr46Ycb94s2KNKwmnz%2FStJq3euLpUSuBmbsKmKou2915ZR5Cp%2FA7xXnK7FO5EHcnem3Xi6gLpAJPXCF51sQxVQn%2BP1fAmlDqEzSnZEVkbhAO3LkZzALdnjzUc2SPyRCdVx70xAnkohQVH%2BuaU7qZtlCtYwJ7MYQqwa1%2BXuPfw9Vb7vgduYqoWMB%2FVIab5uDPe1KnIxZ08reU1PHVTWXcXXyGCEwmYfCYDkXZSIH%2FcnM%2B4oKAu3kEalGX9jxEVvC6VKz4mAdg7O5Q4Ns%2BEKyTR5VqrpisfZcY2VWOX8ipjCuYMTTosY9Lm%2F0qSpU4P%2B2ObuXCbsJIYviK2EsQqj6%2BWNo0L3DEK6L2N7","User-Agent":"PebbleApp/20141016231206 CFNetwork/711.1.12 Darwin/14.0.0","Accept-Language":"nl-nl","Accept-Encoding":"gzip, deflate","Content-Length":"6"}
```

As you can see no data is send within the request.

Anyone have an idea why no data is send with the request?

## Solved

I was able to solve it through the github of pebblejs. For people with the same problem: 
When the 'type' is set to 'json' the ajax library does not only expect the response to be json, but also the data that is posted is posted as json. If you want to gather this data in an array in PHP use the following code:

```
json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);
```